Как запретить изменение размера окна в питоне?
У меня есть змейка, и я не хочу, чтобы пользователь мог изменять размер окна, а как запретить это, я не знаю.
import turtle
import time
import random

delay = 0.1

# Score
score = 0
high_score = 0

# Set up the screen
win = turtle.Screen()
win.title("Snake Game")
win.bgcolor("black")
win.setup(width=600, height=600)
win.tracer(0)

# Snake head
head = turtle.Turtle()
head.speed(0)
head.shape("square")
head.color("white")
head.penup()
head.goto(0, 0)
head.direction = "stop"

# Snake food
food = turtle.Turtle()
food.speed(0)
food.shape("circle")
food.color("red")
food.penup()
food.goto(0, 100)

# Functions
def go_up():
    if head.direction != "down":
        head.direction = "up"

def go_down():
    if head.direction != "up":
        head.direction = "down"

def go_left():
    if head.direction != "right":
        head.direction = "left"

def go_right():
    if head.direction != "left":
        head.direction = "right"

def move():
    if head.direction == "up":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y + 20)
    elif head.direction == "down":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y - 20)
    elif head.direction == "left":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x - 20)
    elif head.direction == "right":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x + 20)

# Keyboard bindings
win.listen()
win.onkeypress(go_up, "w")
win.onkeypress(go_down, "s")
win.onkeypress(go_left, "a")
win.onkeypress(go_right, "d")

# Main game loop
while True:
    win.update()

    # Check for collision with food
    if head.distance(food) < 22:
        # Move the food to a random spot
        x = random.randint(-290, 290)
        y = random.randint(-290, 290)
        food.goto(x, y)

    move()
    time.sleep(delay)


Для того чтобы запретить пользователю изменять размер окна в tkinter, необходимо использовать метод resizable для окна. В данном случае, поскольку вы используете turtle, который основан на tkinter, можно воспользоваться следующим способом:
Добавьте вызов win.cv._rootwindow.resizable(False, False) после настройки экрана. Это отключит возможность изменять размер окна как по горизонтали, так и по вертикали.
Вот код с внесенными изменениями:
...
# Set up the screen
win = turtle.Screen()
win.title("Snake Game")
win.bgcolor("black")
win.setup(width=600, height=600)
win.tracer(0)

# Disable window resizing
win.cv._rootwindow.resizable(False, False)

# Snake head
head = turtle.Turtle()
head.speed(0)
head.shape("square")
head.color("white")
head.penup()
head.goto(0, 0)
head.direction = "stop"
...

Объяснение:
win.cv._rootwindow.resizable(False, False) используется для запрета изменения размера окна. Первый аргумент False отключает изменение размера по горизонтали, второй False отключает изменение размера по вертикали.
Теперь окно будет фиксированного размера, и пользователь не сможет его изменять.

Спасибо, помогло, теперь проигрываю и не могу открыть змейку на полный экран

Если решение помогло, лучший способ отблагодарить - нажать на кнопку "ответ был полезен"
